# Looking for a word to symbolize readiness for battle

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Specifically, I’m looking for a word that would imply readiness, if not giddiness, for a battle, fight, or war. In this particular instance, this person has the odds against them but is absolutely ready, with a smile on their face and determination in their eyes.

Example:

> I looked over and – just from a brief glance – knew that he was ________________.

Comment: Cruisin' for a bruisin'?

Comment: Possibly "bloodthirsty"?

Comment: The former is a phrase, I am really just looking for an adjective. However, if there is a suitable noun, that would be the "golden egg."

Comment: I think the technical term is "battle-ready".

Comment: Also usable, but that is just slightly too generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fired up](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fired-up) means emotionally, and to some extent, physically ready for action. It's very similar to @RichardKayser's 'pumped'.

Comment: Nice. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

How about **pumped** or **ready to roll**?

From The Free Dictionary:

> [**pumped**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pumped): emotionally
>   excited; enthusiastic or eager
>
> [**ready to
>   roll**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Ready+to+Roll): prepared
>   to start doing something

Your example:

> I looked over and--just from a brief glance--knew that he was **pumped**.
>
> I looked over and--just from a brief glance--knew that he was **ready to
>   roll**.

Both of these "imply readiness, if not giddiness, for a battle, fight, or war" and a person who "is absolutely ready, with a smile on their face and determination in their eyes".

Comment: These are the best ones so far.

Comment: @Mayhem Jensen - More ideas: *itching for a fight*, *rarin' to go*, *thirsty for battle* [or revenge].  Tip: if you can find one expression that works, you can use it as a bootstrap to get a list **by using a thesaurus**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to expressions more sophisticated than "combat-ready" or "ready to fight", consider **"on a war footing"**, even if it generally used for a group (country, army, company, ...).

> Definition: the condition of being prepared to undertake or maintain a
>   combat.
>
> Example: *I think I'll approach it differently than, you know, say, my
>   dad who had, you know, had a very - what's the right word for it? - a
>   very - he was perpetually on a war footing with, you know, with the
>   world*.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***[bellicose](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bellicose)*** may fit in your context:

> - demonstrating aggression and willingness to fight.

and  ***[combative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/combative)***:

> - ready or eager to fight; pugnacious.

Oxford Dictionary

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was searching for. Would _truculent_ be an acceptable substitute? I'm just looking for a small list that would fit the description.

Comment: Yes, that also would  convey the meaning you are looking for. You may also consider belligerent.

Comment: @MayhemJensen - No, *truculent* doesn't work for this.

Comment: I don't think bellicose or pugnacious fit your example sentence.  I think they describe someone's general attitude or character.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, ***spoiling for a fight***

> be spoiling for a fight
>
> to be very eager to fight or argue *He says what he thinks, and so people think he always seems to be spoiling for a fight.*
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spoiling+for+a+fight)

Comment: this also works, but I'm looking for a single word, as tagged.

Answer (score 0):

He was "**keen**" for battle - ready, eager, and enthusiastic - blind to their disadvantage and the bloodiness of war.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/keen

Answer (score 0):

Hardened: made or became more severe and less sympathetic.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hardened)
>
> Hardened: having developed a way of dealing with bad experiences so that they no longer upset you :

Answer (score -3):

What about "embattled"?

From Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary (1913) [web1913]:   Embattle \Em*bat"tle\, v. t. [imp. & p. p. {Embattled}; p. pr. &
      vb. n. {Embattling}.] [OF. embataillier; pref. em- (L. in) +
      F. bataille battle. See {Battle}, and cf. {Battlement}.]
      To arrange in order of battle; to array for battle; also, to
      prepare or arm for battle; to equip as for battle.

Comment: Except that the term tends to imply being surrounded by the enemy.

Comment: In that case, recall that the odds are against you, which could imply they are being surrounded so this also works. On the other hand, it sounds too casual and explanatory. thank you for the input.